# Why create JBoss all those transactions

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I have a Restfull service, login:

```
@POST
@Path("login")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public Response login(Credentials credentials) {
   // ask database if token exist
   // create token if necessary
}
```

When the token has to be created, I expect only one transaction, but in the logging I find 4 commits. None of the beans that does the transactions are annotated with @TransactionAttribute.

Why are there 4 commits?

```
2021-03-03 16:34:17,586 DEBUG [xx.x.LoginResource] (default task-1) Login
2021-03-03 16:34:17,586 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-1) BaseTransaction.begin
2021-03-03 16:34:17,591 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-1) BaseTransaction.commit
2021-03-03 16:34:17,592 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-1) BaseTransaction.begin
2021-03-03 16:34:17,594 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-1) BaseTransaction.commit
2021-03-03 16:34:17,595 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-1) BaseTransaction.begin
2021-03-03 16:34:17,596 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-1) BaseTransaction.begin
2021-03-03 16:34:17,597 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-1) BaseTransaction.commit
2021-03-03 16:34:17,610 TRACE [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default task-1) BaseTransaction.commit
```

Comment: How class is declared? Could you please add the class declaration with all annotations to the question?

Comment: Only the @Path:

    @Path("/")
    public class LoginResource {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method-level annotation `@TransactionAttribute` hints at the intent to use [Container-Managed Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html). As per [JAX-RS specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr311/index.html), JAX-RS resources **do not** constitute a transaction boundary by themself, therefore they are not subject to the [Container-Managed Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html).

As of JavaEE 6, only EJBs are subject to [Container-Managed Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html). [JAX-RS specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr311/index.html) explicitly documents the integration with an EJB-enabled container (emphasis is mine):

> In a product that also supports EJB, an implementation MUST support use of stateless and singleton session beans as root resource classes, providers and `Application` subclasses. **JAX-RS annotations MAY be applied to a bean’s local interface or directly to a no-interface bean.** If an `ExceptionMapper` for a `EJBException` or subclass is not included with an application then exceptions thrown by an EJB resource class or provider method MUST be treated as EJB application exceptions: the embedded cause of the `EJBException` MUST be unwrapped and processed as described in section 3.3.4.

In this particular case, it is enough to add the `javax.ejb.Stateless` annotation at the class level:

```
@Path("/")
@Stateless
public class LoginResource {

    @POST
    @Path("login")
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public Response login(Credentials credentials) {
        // ask database if token exist
        // create token if necessary
    }

}
```

You may also omit method-level `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)`, as it is a [default transaction attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html#bncim) for EJBs.